# Looping through a 'for each as' loop in reverse

Tags: vb.net, loops

looking to go backwards through this loop and cant work out the format.

```
For Each subele As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. A `For Each` loop direction can't be controlled. 
What you can do is replace it with a for loop:

```
'' Note: Option infer should be set to ON for this line!
Dim elements = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
For i as Integer = elements.Length To 0 Step -1
    Dim subele As HtmlElement = elements(i)
Next
```

If you only need the last element returned from `GetElementsByTagName` you can simply do this:

```
Dim elements = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
Dim subele As HtmlElement = elements(elements.Length-1) ' or perhaps Count, I'm not sure if this method returns an array, a list, or simply an IEnumerable...
```

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: The only way I am aware of is by reverse iterating the index like above